# Finding dependencies on a given function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, function

How do I find dependencies on a given function `A`? What I need to know is that neither `triggers` nor other `functions` depend on it. Is that possible to do using some kind of query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a query for that:

```
SELECT *
FROM DBA_DEPENDENCIES
WHERE REFERENCED_OWNER = 'YOUR_SCHEMA'
AND REFERENCED_NAME = 'A';
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can Try with this

```
exec dbms_utility.get_dependency('Object_Type', 'Schema_Name','Object');
```

Comment: As of Oracle 12.2, that procedure is deprecated; Oracle recommends querying `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` as the other answers show.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct 
   owner,
   name,
   referenced_name 
from 
   dba_dependencies where referenced_name='fn_name';
```

Answer (score -1):

The Query mentioned below show  which `functions, procedures,triggers` the particular function is used.
you can also check which functions procedures,triggers,packages a particular column is
used using the same query just need to `replace` column name instead of name of function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (NAME) 
  FROM USER_SOURCE 
WHERE UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%NAME OF FUNCTION%';
```